# Xpath input field containing text inserted

Tags: php, html, selenium, xpath, web

I have the following problem:

I have to check via Selenium if an input field has been filled with a expected manually inserted text.

Here's the input field with the value of '50':

```
<input type="text" class="value_per form-control input-sm valid" name="per_slider1" idslider="1" value="50">
```

I won't look for the `@value`, but instead, the value that I can edit in the form.
For clarification, the input's `@value` will be always '50' even if I edit the input text to '100' and I don't know how to get the '100' via Xpath.

I already tried with:

```
//input[@name='per_slider']/text()
```

or

```
//input[@name='per_slider']/@value
```

but they don't work.

If you have a fast solution for this, all comments are appreciated.

I'm using `PHPunit` to test a website via `Selenium`(This info should be useless).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

It should work!
Usually only the displayed "value" attribute in the browser-tools do not get updated, but actually it gets updated and you can pull it ;-)

**Assuming that you enter your new value and press enter or tab to another element or sth.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want that value which have 100 only then use something like below:-

```
//input[@name='per_slider1' and @value='100']
```

The xpath you are trying

```
//input[@name='per_slider']/@value
```

You should use. You have missed 1 after per_slider

```
//input[@name='per_slider1']/@value
```

Hope it will help you :)